# Как разместить блок относительно элемента?

Tags: html, css

Код: [jsfiddle.net/2x1wbo8q](http://jsfiddle.net/2x1wbo8q)
При клике должен появляться зеленый блок, расположенный относительно синего, как показано на [картинке](http://i.piccy.info/i9/b4d90605419067f93c3768a8c978b42d/1411572753/1932/805169/click.png). Как написать css зеленого блока?

```
  <div class="b"><span id="click">click me</span></div>

.b {
    margin-top: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    background: red;
}

#click {
    background: blue;
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/b6hLvp2m/

Comment: @soledar10, если я пишу вот так http://jsfiddle.net/b6hLvp2m/3/ , то почему блок появляется на том же месте?! У меня текст в красном блоке будет размещаться посредине, и длина текста в синем блоке также не будет известна заранее. То есть зеленый блок должен всегда идти за синим на равном расстоянии (как будто подсказка, только всегда слева и наполовину высоту синего блока выше).

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/u21mrdu0/

Comment: @soledar10 Спасибо.